# jquery check if string exists as function before calling

Tags: jquery

How come `isFunction` isn't working for hide/show?

http://jsbin.com/tavirasi/1/edit?js,output

```
$('.form select[data-change]').change(function(){
    var $el = $($(this).data('change'));
    if($el.length){
        var action = $(this).find(':selected').data('action');
        if($.isFunction(action)){
            $el[action]();
        }
    }
}).change();
```

HTML

```
<form action="" class="form">

    <select name="question" data-change="input[name=customer_question]">
      <option data-action="hide">Mothers maiden name</option>
      <option data-action="foo">Prevent error</option>
      <option data-action="show">Custom question</option>
    </select>

  <input type="text" name="customer_question" style="display:none" />

  </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a string which of course is not a function. It should be:

```
if ( $.isFunction( $el[action] ) )
```

Comment: Oh thats obvious now cheers, was thinking that it was checking if the jquery function existed. So it only calls the function when you have the `()` at the end